# excel 2003 can`t edit comments (user)

Tags: excel

I have a .xls file of excel 2003.
There are a lot of comments.
I can`t edit it.
right click ->edit comments
for example:
I have comment:

```
Ludmila: comment goes here
```

Then

```
Ludmila: comment goes here
Dezigo:new comment..!
```

I tryed to do:
Tools-options-general (change my name to Ludmila),but it`s not work..
Like it

```
 Ludmila: comment goes here
 Ludmila:new comment..
```

**and comment goes here** -can`t edit it.
file is not protected.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e9c80bc417.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e9c80bc417.png)

Comment: why?
answers,didn`t help me. :(

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me and no web posting was helpful. Make the column, where the comment is,  wider and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the worksheet is protected?